# How to align strings to right, and chop them if too long in Raku?

Tags: raku

The important part is, I want the alignment to hold, so the string gets chopped from left. I tried `substr`, but that crashes if a string is not long enough. Currently I have a similar solution to this:

```pl
> my $xs = (0..4).kv.map(-> $i, $x { ('a'..'z')[0..$i-1].join })
( a ab abc abcd)
> $xs.map({ sprintf '%3.3s', $_ }).raku
("   ", "  a", " ab", "abc", "abc").Seq
```

But the problem is, the string still gets chopped from right, not left (chopping behaves as if aligned to left, not right). I am looking for something which would return:

```pl
("   ", "  a", " ab", "abc", "bcd")
```

The difference is the last item where from "abcd" the "a" should be chopped, not the "d".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve that in a few different ways, but I'd probably break it down into two operations: ① take the last 3 characters (if any): `.comb.tail(3).join`; ② format the output with space-padding: `.fmt("%3s")`.

Putting that in one line would replace your second line with:

```raku
 > $xs.map({ .comb.tail(3).join.fmt("%3s")}).raku
("   ", "  a", " ab", "abc", "bcd").Seq
```

Another alternative (which avoids the round-trip into a list) would be to add the padding first:

```raku
 > $xs.map({.fmt("%3s").substr(*-3, *)}).raku
("   ", "  a", " ab", "abc", "bcd").Seq
```

(Oh, and you didn't ask about this, but it would probably be more idiomatic Raku to save the list of strings into an `@xs` variable instead of an `$xs` one in many cases)

Comment: Thank you, both approaches work nicely! I was trying something like your first solution, but didn't know about `comb` and used `split("")` which didn't work the way I was expecting. Also a second thanks for the `$` vs `@`. I don't have experience with perl and I am only starting with raku, and these things (sigils?) I haven't really seen in any other language. I appreciate such tips :).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if flip is expensive, but:

```
$xs.map({$_.flip.substr(0,3).flip})
```

avoids the list, fmt, and the issue with substr.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the aligning, I got `("", "a", "ab", "abc", "bcd").Seq`. I think `fmt` or something else for padding would still have to be used.

Comment: ```$xs.map(*.flip.substr(0,3).flip).fmt("%3s")``` should do it.